# C# SQL - Search address, if not found Insert address with street record already known in DB

Tags: c#, sql, search, sql-insert

I'm creating a search for address, if address not found than create address with same road name within database.

---

*Example:*
Step 1. **User Input (Types in inclocroad.Text)** - 49 London Road, Camden
Step 2. **Script Process** - Searches for similar matches to 49 London Road, Camden
Step 3. **Script Process** - Found Match = London Road, Camden, London, EN18 7RF
Step 4. **Script Process** - Replaces London Road, Camden with London Road, Camden, London, EN18 7RF in inclocroad.text
Step 5. **Script Process** - Insert new record into database: addresses with new inclocroad.text data if not valid row already
Step 6. **Script Process** - Shows new display screen with new valid address from DB.

---

At the moment my code can search for similar addresses without having the property name / number
however it can not find anything in the database if I have put something infront of it. (E.G. It can find London Road, Camden and replace it with the full address but if I type 49 London Road, Camden it can't find anything similiar in the DB and just inserts a new address with 49 London Road, Camden - not the full address already known in the database.
My current database already holds all the street names in the specific area.

If someone can assist me in making my code do above, that'll be awesome. 
Step 1 and 6 already works, just the other steps don't. I've been banging my head for ages and uses different types of methods I have found on the internet with no success. 
I don't really want to add another textbox just to put the property name / number. I would love it just to be one textbox.

SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(@Settings.Default.database);
con1.Open();
string qu = "SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE road LIKE '%'+@address+'%' OR postcode LIKE '%'+@address+'%' OR full_address LIKE '%'+@address+'%' OR property LIKE '%'+@address+'%' OR full_address2 LIKE '%'+@address+'%' ";
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(qu, con1);

```
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", inclocroad.Text);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            bool recordfound = dr.Read();



            if (recordfound)
            {
                


                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@Settings.Default.database);
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT full_address FROM addresses WHERE full_address=@fulladdress) INSERT INTO addresses (property, postcode, road, borough, town, district, full_address, full_address2) VALUES (@property, @postcode, @road, @borough, @town, @district, @fulladdress, @fulladdress2)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@property", dr["property"].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", dr["postcode"].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@road", dr["road"].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@town", dr["town"].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@borough", dr["borough"].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@district", dr["district"].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fulladdress", dr["full_address"].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fulladdress2", dr["full_address2"].ToString());
                int affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();


                LoadAddresses loadadd = new LoadAddresses();
                
                statusloc.Text = dr["district"].ToString();
                loadadd.searchlable.Text = inclocroad.Text;
            loadadd.ShowDialog();


        }
        
            else
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Address not found.", "Error");
        }


        con1.Close();
```

Comment: First look: you don't have a parameter called `@address` in your sql.

Comment: Apologies, I have just uploaded the full script. I was tinkering around before posting and didn't realize I removed and changed it. This is how far I got to now.

Comment: Another quick look: don't put quotes around your parameters: `'%@address%'`

Comment: That's been fixed however still stuck on the LIKE param where it can find London Road, Camden but can't find 49 London Road, Camden

Comment: `It can find London Road, Camden and replace it with the full address but if I type 49 London Road, Camden it can't find anything similiar in the DB and just inserts a new address with 49 London Road, Camden` - this is expected. In order for the wildcard compare you mentioned above to work, the database value has to contain exactly what is inside the `'%'` at least once. `London Road, Camden, London, EN18 7RF` does not contain `49 London Road, Camden`. So the compare returns false.

Comment: It's ok, if someone can assist in some how getting it to work. I've managed to get it to work however I must use two textbox's instead of one which I was hoping for :(.